# How can I create CSS breadcrumbs with clip-path?

Tags: css, coordinates, breadcrumbs, clip-path

I'm trying to make a breadcrumbs path using `clip-path`.

```css
#clip span {
  padding: 3px 20px;
  background-color: #666;
  color: white;
  display: inline-block;
  clip-path: polygon(0 0, 90% 0, 100% 50%, 90% 100%, 0 100%, 10% 50%);
}
```

```html
<div id="clip">
  <span>hello</span><span>tiny</span><span>world</span><span>welcome!</span>
</div>
```

which gives

[image]

While I like the simplicity of that method, the problem comes from the coordinates `90%`, which are relative to the length of the word. Thus "welcome!" does not have the same arrow angle as "tiny".

Of course, I could add two blank blocks between the words that would stick to previous and followings spans, shaped as required.

But is there a way to specify something like the "geometry" coordinates style of X-Windows for a `polygon`, something like `-10px` (which would count from the right/bottom of an element ; thus for a 100 pixels element, that would give 90 pixels, meaning 10 pixels from the opposite side of an element)?

Thus, the rule, "geometry" like, would be something like (which doesn't work in CSS, since -10 pixels counts from the left/top)

```
clip-path: polygon(0 0, -10px 0, 100% 50%, -10px 100%, 0 100%, 10px 50%);
```

Comment: I know it has nothing to do with the question but is a solution with :before/:after element will be an alternative for you ? or you know how you can do it but you need to see if how with clip-path ?

Comment: Have you tried using `<fill-rule>` (`closest-side` or `farthest-side`) or maybe to use SVG `clip-path: url(#svgID);` ?

Comment: @Krusader I prefer to avoid the SVG solution - as for "fill-rule" how would you use it, in this case?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have a detailed article about creating such shapes: *[How to create Breadcrumb Navigation with CSS](https://verpex.com/blog/website-tips/how-to-create-breadcrumb-navigation-with-css)*

---

You can try `calc` and you use something like `(100% - 10px)`. It will behave like a negative coordinate for the right of the element:

```css
#clip span {
  padding: 3px 20px;
  background-color: #666;
  color: white;
  display: inline-block;
  clip-path: polygon(0 0, calc(100% - 10px) 0, 100% 50%, calc(100% - 10px) 100%, 0 100%, 10px 50%);
}
```

```html
<div id="clip">
  <span>hello</span><span>tiny</span><span>world</span><span>welcome!</span>
</div>
```

I would also suggest to consider other ways more supported.

Using multiple background:

```css
#clip span {
  color: white;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 3px 20px;
  border-right:10px solid transparent;
  border-left:10px solid transparent;

  background:
    linear-gradient(to top    right,transparent 47%,#666 51%) top left     border-box,
    linear-gradient(to top    left ,transparent 47%,#666 51%) bottom right border-box,
    linear-gradient(to bottom right,transparent 47%,#666 51%) bottom left  border-box,
    linear-gradient(to bottom left ,transparent 47%,#666 51%) top right    border-box,
    #666 padding-box;
  background-size:10px 50%;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<div id="clip">
  <span>hello</span><span>tiny</span><span>world</span><span>welcome!</span>
</div>
```

Using pseudo element and skew transformation:

```css
#clip span {
  color: white;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 3px 15px;
  margin:0 5px;
  position:relative;
  z-index:0;
}
#clip span:before,
#clip span:after {
  content:"";
  position:absolute;
  z-index:-1;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  height:50%;
  background:#666;
}
#clip span:before {
  top:0;
  transform:skewX(45deg);
}
#clip span:after {
  bottom:0;
  transform:skewX(-45deg);
}
```

```html
<div id="clip">
  <span>hello</span><span>tiny</span><span>world</span><span>welcome!</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Simple as expected, thanks (bit worried about the browser support though). Didn't know this was possible in css!

Comment: @ringø yes i thought about it, but i think you will only face issue with IE